# java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: xamarin.forms

Follwing is the code piece which works in my sample project.but it is not working in my actual project.

```
 await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
 if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable||!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
 {
   await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
   return;
  }
 var filePath = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(newPlugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
  {
     SaveToAlbum = true
  });
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:560)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:534)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:376)
    at md5a3e164e78ade0c22cefea770ddd0bc49.MediaPickerActivity.n_onCreate(NativeMethod)     at md5a3e164e78ade0c22cefea770ddd0bc49.MediaPickerActivity.onCreate(MediaPickerActvity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
```

Comment: Did you add the right permissions and file-provider tags in you project? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: I haven't added any permissions. Nuget Package will take care of all the permissions. My Sample project is working fine.

Comment: Did you check? Because I have seen cases where the Nuget didn't take care of it. It has to be something related as I see a term like 'loadxmlmetadata'.

Comment: Can you please provide what all the permissions we need to give..Because i tried permissions like camera,external storage And external read_write and all.

Comment: I think it is more useful if you post your XML files since the error lies with you.

Comment: Which xml androidmanifest or my design xml?

Comment: Your androidmanifest and `file_paths.xml` if you have created it as instructed by the plugin

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks man.. it works fine  adding file_paths.xml file in project.

Comment: I've updated it to an answer, please accept it

Answer (score 5):

Besides adding the right permissions, please make sure you have added the additional `file_paths.xml` file under a folder called `xml` in the `Resources` folder in your Android project if you are targetting Android N (API level 24+).

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/files/Pictures" />
    <external-path name="my_movies" path="Android/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/files/Movies" />
</paths>
```

Where **YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME** must be set to your app package name!

```
Then add this in your `application` tag in the `androidmanifest.xml` file:

<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
                android:authorities="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider" 
                android:exported="false" 
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

Again, make sure your **YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME** is set to your app package name.

For more on what you need to configure when using this plugin, please make sure you read the documentation on the [Github page](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

Comment: the bet explanation.. I did not know that needs to folder xml

Answer (score 0):

I got above problem even I already did all above things. I got fixed this issue in my case for android to set "Use Latest Platform(Android7.1)" for "Compile Using android version: (Target Framework)" in "Application" tab of android project properties.